# pathlib folders are not visible from windows explorer

Tags: python, windows, powershell, explorer, pathlib

Using the pathlib module i am creating a folder under AppData/Roaming with mkdir() but it will not show up in my windows explorer.
When i search the directory AppData/Roaming the desired folder is listed there. When using os.path.exists i also get a True. Still no sign of it in the windows explorer.

I have checked showing hidden folders.

In the image below the desired folder is circled in the cmd (right) but not found in the explorer (left).

Does anybody have experienced similar? Why is this happening?
[image]

Comment: It doesn't show even after a refresh of the windows explorer?

Comment: Even after a reboot. I have this problem for a week now. And at every startup pathlib finds those folders.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer/solution to this? I have the same problem.